# racket. Implement the Ackermann's function

Tags: racket

I'm trying to understand, but so far I can not make myself. When I see the finished solution is easier to understand how to do it. This is my first exercise, the others want to do it myself, but need to understand how to implement it.
Please help me how to write a racket function.

Implement the Ackermann's function A. It takes two parameters, x and y, and works as follows:

```
if y = 0, then it returns 0;
if x = 0, then it returns 2*y;
if y = 1, then it returns 2;
else, it calls itself (function A) with x = x-1 and y = A ( x, (y - 1) )
```

The project is given

```
#lang racket/base

(require rackunit)

;; BEGIN

;; END

(check-equal? (A 1 10) 1024)
(check-equal? (A 2 4) 65536)
(check-equal? (A 3 3) 65536)
```

Comment: as usual, what have you tried?

Comment: (define (A x y)
  (cond ((= y 0) 0)
        ((= x 0) (* 2 y)
        ((= y 1) 2)))

And then I do not understand how to do

Comment: so what you don't understand is recursive call.

Comment: I did not know how to write this part here (else, it calls itself (function A) with x = x-1 and y = A (x, (y - 1)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a straightforward translation, you just have to write the formula using Scheme's syntax:

```
(define (A x y)
  (cond ((= y 0) 0)       ; if y = 0, then it returns 0
        ((= x 0) (* 2 y)) ; if x = 0, then it returns 2*y
        ((= y 1) 2)       ; if y = 1, then it returns 2
        (else (A (- x 1)  ; else it calls itself (function A) with x = x-1
                 (A x (- y 1)))))) ; and y = A ( x, (y - 1))
```

Comment: That's just the syntax I did not understand until the end. And ask for help because that would understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
#lang racket

(define (ack x y)
  (match* (x y)
    [(_ 0) 0]       ; if y = 0, then it returns 0
    [(0 y) (* 2 y)] ; if x = 0, then it returns 2*y
    [(_ 1) 2]       ; if y = 1, then it returns 2
    [(x y) (ack (- x 1) (ack x (- y 1)))]))
```